# Reinstall apps/services via phone directly?

Tags: adb, usb-debugging, developer-options, disable-app, tecno

I uninstalled certain apps/services via adb, then disabled the USB Debugging option. After restart the phone's settings option is not working. Please suggest how to enable developer options, usb debugging so that I can reinstall the same for user 0.

At max I am able to see list of system apps. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Resolved the issue using 3P apps for adding shortcuts to following:

1. About Phone. (Entered Developer Mode)
2. Developer Options. (Enabled USB debugging)
3. Connected via USB, ran adb shell cmd successfully from here.

App used - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=any.shortcut but any shortcut app works.

Note: `*#*#4636#*#*` and `*#*#34971539#*#*` didn't work for my phone. You can give it a try.